# Zipping a folder using 7-Zip from an asp page

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, cmd, 7zip

I am trying to zip a folder from an asp page. This is my code:

```
zipFolderName=folderName &"Zipped.zip"
command="cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip & "
command = command & "7z a -tzip " & zipFolderName & " """ & folderName & """"
Response.Write command

set objshell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
objShell.exec (command)
set objshell=nothing
```

The command that is written in the `Response.Write` is

```
cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip & 7z a -tzip D:/saveAll/DocumentsZipped.zip "D:/saveAll/Documents"
```

When I run this command in a cmd window it works just fine. But my asp page shows an error:

```
WshShell.Exec error '80070002'
```

The system cannot find the file specified.

The error is on the objShell.exe command-line.

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `C:\Program Files\7-Zip` between double quotes, because the path contains a space. Also, `cd` and `&` are CMD-builtins, so you need to run the command line in `CMD`.

Change this:

```
command="cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip & "
```

into this:

```
command = "%COMSPEC% /c cd ""C:\Program Files\7-Zip"" & "
```

Comment: Hi, I found this script, written 9 years ago. I have tried it and it does not give any error, but the zip file is not created. Can you give me some help? Thank you