# Download multiple files in classic asp?

Tags: vbscript, download, asp-classic

I need to stream two files back to the browser in one request to the server. This is what I am currently using to stream one file:

```
Private Sub DownloadFile(strFile, strFileName)
    Dim objStream
    Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile(strFile)
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    Response.Addheader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFileName

    Do While Not objStream.EOS
        Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read(1024 * 256)
    Loop
    objStream.Close
    Set objStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

Which works great, but when I try to do this:

```
Call DownloadFile(File1, FileName1)
Call DownloadFile(File2, FileName2)
```

I only get the first file sent to the browser.

Anyone know how I can send two files in one request?

I need the files to remain as separate files, so I'm not sure if that rules out combining them into one stream.

Comment: Your only options are to download one file at a time, or to download a .ZIP file of more than one file.  One HTTP Request = One HTTP Response

Comment: You could use AJAX to call an accessible function which allows to pass the some identifer which identifies which download to send back, then do it multiple times to download multiple files.

Comment: I am currently looking into the zip file option, but it appears I will need a third party app to zip the files up in classic asp. Not ideal with my situation. I hadn't even considered AJAX. Will vet that option on Monday. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: To zip the files, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339323/zipping-a-folder-using-7-zip-from-an-asp-page). It's about folder, but files should be exactly the same.

Comment: I've decided to simply open a new tab with links to download each file separately. This accomplishes my overall goal without any third party apps. Hence the user has to click on each link to get all the files, but there are never more than 2 files at a time anyway. 

I still may go back at some point and attempt the AJAX method. @ShadowWizard - that method requires 7-zip which is not installed on the servers I need this to work on. I don't want to go down the 3rd party method with my clients. Thanks

Comment: Cheers, thanks for updating.